# Isometric 3d collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, isometric

I'm making an isometric map for a game, I can draw it, but I don't know how to implement a sort of 3d collision detection without Threejs or other 3d library.

It is possible? Maybe make the block an Object can help? I have searched a lot on the web, but I found only libraries. Thank you!

This is my JavaScript code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
 width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
 height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
 stop = false;

var tw, th;
var player;

setup();
draw();

function setup(){
  ctx.translate(width/2,50);

  tw = 60; //tile width
  th = 30; // tile height
  player = new Player(2,3,2);

};

function draw(){

  ctx.clearRect(-width/2,-50,width*1.5,height+50);

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        drawBlock(i,j,1,tw,th);
      }
    }

    if(!stop){
     requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
}

function drawBlock(x,y,z,w,h){

 var top = "#eeeeee",
     right = '#cccccc',
     left = '#999999';

 ctx.save();
 ctx.translate((x-y)*w/2,(x+y)*h/2);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(-w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = top;
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(-w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(-w/2,h/2);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = left;
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(w/2,h/2-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h-z*h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(0,h);
 ctx.lineTo(w/2,h/2);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = right;
 ctx.fill();

 ctx.restore();

}

function drawTile(x,y,stroke,col){

 ctx.save();
 ctx.translate((x-y)*tw/2,(x+y)*th/2);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.lineTo(tw/2,th/2);
 ctx.lineTo(0,th);
 ctx.lineTo(-tw/2,th/2);
 ctx.closePath();
 if(stroke){
  ctx.stroke();
 }else{
  ctx.fillStyle = col;
  ctx.fill();
 }

 ctx.restore();

}

function Player(x,y,z){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
  this.w = 10; //width
  this.h = 10; //height
}
```

```css
canvas{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It's not really clear, to me at least, what your goal is. Could you compare it to some existing game perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure you need 3d collision detection? If you are making a tile based game and dont care about collisions on the y-axis, you could either just do 2d collisions. An even easier approach, since it is a tile-based game, would be to just check if objects are on a specific tile

Comment: When I developed an isometric game once, I made a good experience with keeping the game mechanics completely orthogonal and do the conversion to isometric in the rendering system. This drastically reduced the mental acrobatics I had to do when implementing things like collision detection and movement vectors.

Answer (score 0):

to compare any box with one axis-aligned box I use this approach:

```
method boolean checkCornerColission(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z3, width, height, depth):
  return x1 > x2 and x1 < x2+width and y1 > y2 and y1 < y2+height and z1 > z2 and z1 < z2+depth;

method boolean checkColission():
    for corner i=0 to 7:
      if checkCornerColission(x[i],y[i],z[i]...):
         return true;
    return false
```